# Deploying Camel CXF Proxy into Red Hat JBoss Fuse

Tags: maven, cxf, apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I have followed this [CXF Proxy Example](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html) and it runs successfully as described.

Now I want to deploy the CXF Proxy Example into JBoss-Fuse as OSGI Bundle. I am following this instruction [Deploying the Apache Camel Route](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.0/html-single/Security_Guide/index.html#CamelCXF-DeployRoute). But this popping me out with this error:

```
JBossFuse:admin@root> install -s mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-example-cxf-proxy/2.12.2

Bundle ID: 281
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
        Unable to start bundle mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-example-cxf-proxy/2.12.2:
Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.camel.camel-example-cxf-proxy [281]: Unable
to resolve 281.0: missing requirement [281.0] osgi.wiring.package; 
(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.spring)(version>=2.12.0)(!(version>=2.13.0)))

JBossFuse:admin@root>
```

I didn't change anything. Just used their example as it is. They have this on their pom.xml

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>examples</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.2</version>
  </parent>
```

I tried this by changing the version into `2.9.0.fuse-70-097` But the error is same(just with a changed version number)

```
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.camel.spring)
(version>=2.9.0)(!(version>=2.10.0)))
```

Comment: `features:list | grep spring` - have you got `camel-spring` installed? `list | grep spring` - which bundle version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly tried with several versions by replacing it in `pom.xml` and suddenly it worked for me when i hit the following version:

```
<version>2.10.0</version>
```

I don't know why it worked for me. But, just found me lucky!